# Sycing new Mac with existing Document folder from iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud

I have a new Macbook Pro and I want to sync my Mac Mini Document folder using iCloud. It was not syncing so I signed out of iCloud and signed back in. Now my Document and Desktops are blank. How do I map my local Document folder to my iCloud folder so they are sync'd when I move between the two machines?

Comment: When you signed out of iCloud did it ask you what to do with files? If so - you probably just need to use spotlight to locate the files and drag them back in (move is fine) to the cloud synchronized folders. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204055 (Here the copy is made by a press and hold of the Option key and drag the file to a new location)

Comment: Yes I kept a copy of the files locally, I would like to have an exact mirror for my documents folder from my Mac Mini